# Reducers composition vs shared actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, state, reducers

Redux (with typescript) *newbie* here!

Coming from *backend* (java) development, using `typescript` is a must because of type checking, but using `typescript` for producing a shared state is being a pain for us, because a lot of boilerplate code as been written and a lot of type checking failed, but this is not the really question, just a context.

Currently, we had a challenge to make a react app with `typescript` that consumes a rest API that is not controlled by our team. This API is very standard and normalized in a way that an entity never brings related entities (child's) in response, so is not expanded. In order to get the child's, a second API call has to be made. So far so good, but this gave us a challenge in the implementation of the redux state shape.

When our app implementation started, we opt out for using a `byId/allIds` shape for each entity state slice. This was a nice decision because it helped a lot when we use `useSelector`. But as I said before, the rest API in our case doesn't retrieve expanded child's, so handling all `byId/allIds` relationships between related entities has become a problem to maintain.

For instance, let's use the typical **Post - Comment** model in order to express our problem. Imagine a state tree like this:

```
{
    posts : {
        byId : {
            "p1" : {
                id : "p1",
                comments : ["c1", "c2"]
            },
        },
        allIds : ["p1"]
    },
    comments : {
        byId : {
            "c1" : {
                id : "c1",
            },
            "c2" : {
                id : "c2",
            },
        },
        allIds : ["c1", "c2"]
    }
}
```

Obviously, if this state shares the same `reducer`, it's easy to propagate the *post-comments* relation data, because all the state is accessible. But what happens if post's and comment's have their own `reducer`? This is not a problem if the post's API brings the comments id's, but in our case that's not possible. In our case, to get the comments relate to a post, a second API call (`getCommentsByPost`) has to be made, and then propagated by a different reducer.

In order to solve this, we decide to share actions (e.g. `FETCH_COMMENTS_BY_POST`) between reducers of related entites. This works, but as soon I was learning more about `redux`, I was surprised that *reduce composition* is an option too.

If we had opt-out for *reduce composition*, the root reducer of post's/comment's handles the shared action, and it also solves the problem.

My question is: in a scalable app (the model is still growing), what is the best option for this? *shared actions* or *reduce composition* for related entities?